# Getting "Could not create local repository" error when building Debian package

Tags: debian, packaging, maven

I am trying to build a debian package against Debian stretch. The `debian/rules` file is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

%:
        dh $@

override_dh_auto_build:
        mvn clean package
```

When I build it using `pbuilder-buildpackage` I get this build error:

```
mvn -e clean package
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[ERROR] Could not create local repository at /nonexistent/.m2/repository -> [Help 1]
```

How do I resolve this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debian packages can’t rely on a home directory during builds. This is enforced in `pbuilder` with the `/nonexistent` home.

To fix this, you need to supply the appropriate options to Maven so that it places its repository in `/tmp`. But really, instead of doing that, you should build-depend on `maven-debian-helper` and let `dh` work its magic. Look at [the Java packages in Debian](https://qa.debian.org/developer.php?email=pkg-java-maintainers%40lists.alioth.debian.org) for examples.